# PL - SQL Loop how to take datas

Tags: loops

I do have a table named object_list and I want to delete some of the objects due to some file types.

I count the # of objects first, and then I want to check one by one.

I am a new developer so trying to explain one by one so please help me how I can check the objects in the below loop from a table.

Thank you.

```
BEGIN
select count(object) into counter from OBJECT_LIST;
FOR Lcntr IN 1..counter
LOOP 
select object as obje from CSICONTROL.CM_OBJECT_LIST;
dbms_output.put_line(obje);
END LOOP;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, use a `FOR IN` loop instead.

```
BEGIN
   FOR o IN (SELECT * FROM object_list) LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(o.object);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```